# Teradata SQL Assistance to discern if Previous Row is a specific location and within a set time frame to give me a 1-count (Flag)

Tags: teradata

I am using Teradata. The query below runs, but somehow, I cannot get it to calculate at each hospital admission looking back to previous row if the admission is to an ED and if so is it within 1 day. It works if I limit my data to a single MEMBER_NO and there is one Hospital admission, but when there are several over a few years, it will not give me "1" in "ED Visit within 1 Day of this Hospital Admit" column. Also, I am not able to get it Null at each start of MEMBER_NO for the "Previous LOCATION" and Null at the end for the "Next LOCATION."

```
SELECT js.*
  ,CASE
     WHEN LOCATION = 'Hospital'
     THEN Count(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'Hospital' AND "Days Since ED Discharge"  <= 1 THEN 1 END)
          Over (PARTITION BY TRIM(MEMBER_NO) 
                ORDER BY DISCHARGE_DATE, ADMIT_DATE
                RESET WHEN LOCATION = 'HOSPITAL')
   END AS "ED Visit within 1 Day of this Hospital Admit"

  ,CASE
     WHEN LOCATION = 'Hospital'
     THEN Count(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'Nursing Facility' AND "Days Since Last Hospital Discharge"  <= 7 THEN 1 END)
          Over (PARTITION BY TRIM(MEMBER_NO)
                ORDER BY DISCHARGE_DATE, ADMIT_DATE
                RESET WHEN LOCATION = 'HOSPITAL')
   END AS "Nursing Facility Admit within 7 Days after this Hospital Discharge"
   
  
FROM
( 
  SELECT CLIENT, TRIM(MEMBER_NO) "MEMBER ID", AGE, ADMIT_NO, LOCATION, ADMIT_DATE, DISCHARGE_DATE
, COALESCE(MIN(LOCATION) over (order by ADMIT_NO rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding), LOCATION) "Previous LOCATION"
, COALESCE(MIN(LOCATION) over (order by ADMIT_NO rows between 1 following and 1 following), LOCATION) "Next LOCATION"


,CASE
  WHEN LOCATION = 'Hospital'
        THEN ADMIT_DATE - 
             MIN(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'ED' THEN DISCHARGE_DATE END)
             Over (PARTITION BY TRIM(MEMBER_NO) 
                   ORDER BY DISCHARGE_DATE, ADMIT_DATE
                   ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
      END AS "Days Since ED Discharge"  
     
,CASE
  WHEN LOCATION <> 'Hospital'
        THEN ADMIT_DATE -
             Max(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'Hospital' THEN DISCHARGE_DATE END)
             Over (PARTITION BY TRIM(MEMBER_NO) 
                   ORDER BY DISCHARGE_DATE, ADMIT_DATE
                   ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
      END AS "Days Since Last Hospital Discharge" 
      
  
   FROM CLAIMS_DB.FACILITY_CLAIMS 
   WHERE ADMIT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2020-12-31'
 ) AS js;
```

Here is the display of the result of the query now. The cells shaded in red are incorrect. J6 should be "0" and L6 should be "1". As stated earlier, if I change the date range to only have one Hospital location reported then J6 works. Also, F2 and G8 should be Null. [image]

Comment: Your various location calcs will never be null, because you are always coalescing it with the location column.

Comment: Your `days since ed discharge` is also working.   On row 2, you take the minimum discharge date of all rows for that member id, which is 2017-12-11.  Admit_date on that row is 2018-10-29.  That's a difference of 322 days. I think your logic here is the issue. If you can tell us what you're trying to do, maybe we can help.

Comment: Andrew - for the location column, I was expecting that every beginning of new patient that the "Previous" would be NULL and the end of each patient's lists of admissions that the "Next" would be Null.

Yes, the "Days Since ED Discharge" works only for the first "Hospital" location. It doesn't reset. On row 6 it should be 0 as this patient was seen in the ED the same day before being admitted to the hospital.

Comment: All - I found the issue with ED Days calculation - I needed to change MIN(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'ED' THEN DISCHARGE_DATE END) to MAX(CASE.....

Answer (score 0):

Solution for properly calculating the "Days since ED Visit" at each Hospital Admit date is:

```
,CASE
  WHEN LOCATION = 'Hospital'
        THEN ADMIT_DATE - 
             MAX(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'ED' THEN DISCHARGE_DATE END)
             Over (PARTITION BY TRIM(MEMBER_NO) 
                   ORDER BY DISCHARGE_DATE, ADMIT_DATE
                   ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
      END AS "Days Since ED Discharge"
```

And the solution to getting Previous and Next Locations correct even for NULLs is not to use COALESCE, but instead do this:

```
, MIN(LOCATION) OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER_NO ORDER BY ADMIT_NO ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) "Previous LOCATION"
, MIN(LOCATION) OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER_NO ORDER BY ADMIT_NO ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) "Next LOCATION"
```